# How do I remove a specific CSS class with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to remove the btn class for items that only contain an extra argument in the class name like so:

```
<input type="button" class="btn btn-mini btn-success email-user" id="emailid5" value="Email Tester">
```

I only want to remove the .btn class for any class name that also contains email-user.

My current attempt is failing:

```
$('.btn email-user').remove();
```

Any idea what I'm missing?

Comment: `$('.btn.email-user').removeClass('.btn')`

Comment: $('input.email-user').removeClass('btn');

Comment: Every time you use StackOverflow [before using Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=How+do+I+remove+a+specific+CSS+class+with+jquery), `$DEITY` kills a webserver.

Comment: Wait. Wut? This isn't a personal search engine? :(

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[$.fn.removeClass](https://api.jquery.com/removeclass/) should do the trick. You first select the element, then remove the css class using `removeClass` method.

```
var $el = $(".btn.email-user");
$el.removeClass("btn");
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [removeClass](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/)

```
$('.btn.email-user').removeClass('btn');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in plain javascript too without jquery

```
var c=document.getElementsByClassName("email-user")
var pos=-1;
for (i=0;i<c.length;i++){
    pos=c[i].className.indexOf("btn")
    if (pos!=-1){
    alert("old classname is "+c[i].className)
        c[i].setAttribute("class",
            ((pos==0) ? "" : c[i].className.substring(0,pos)) + 
            c[i].className.substring(pos+3,c[i].className.length))
    alert("new classname is "+c[i].className)
    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

```
jQuery('#emailid5').removeClass('btn');
```